# connect to a slice of an array of connectors

Tags: modelica

I have an array of connectors, and I want to connect another, smaller array of similar connectors, to a slice of this connector array.  Example with `a` an array of `x` connectors, `b` an array of `y` connectors, `x < y`:

```
connect(a[:], b[1:x]); // works fine
connect(a[:], b[2:x+1]); // gives an error
```

The error I get in the second case (when checking the model in Dymola 2012) says:

```
Error: Failed to expand connect(a[:], b[2:x+1])
```

Is this a language or tool limitation?  And is there a workaround (besides using for loops to connect each individual connector)?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't simply an issue of operator precedence?  Did you try b[2:(x+1)]?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and in that case, the `()` are even removed in the error message.

Comment: EDIT: but this works: `connect(a[:], b[1:x+1-1]);` so it's related to the starting position being different from 1

Answer (score 2):

That must be a tool limitation because the specification says:

> Subscripts in a connector reference shall be parameter expressions or the special operator “:”.

The only workaround I can think of is a for-equation or the more obvious: filing a bug report to the Dymola team. I will do the same for OpenModelica (it generates equations, but the wrong ones).

Answer (score 2):

I think we need more code here to understand what is going on.  I don't see any apparent limitation in Dymola.  For example, the following code works fine in Dymola 2012 FD01:

```
model SlicedConnectors 
  parameter Integer n(start=5);
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput a[n];
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput b[2*n];
equation 
  connect(a[:],b[1:n]);
  connect(a[:],b[(n+1):(2*n)]);
end SlicedConnectors;
```

So it doesn't seem to be slicing itself that is the issue but probably something more complicated (something about the specific connectors, variability of sizing, etc).